# Macro to Save as from Excel to .txt file with same file name and same location as original file

Tags: vba, macros

I am trying to write a macro to save as excel file to a .txt file but with the same original filename as the excel file and the same path as the excel file. If i record a macro it has me pick a path and a file name and when I run the macro again it chooses the same path and same file name.

Could someone please help me. I need a simple macro that can do this please. This is the one I recorded but I can't figure out how to edit it to make it save as the same filename as in the original excel file and in the same path as the original excel file.

```
  Sub saveastxt()
'
' saveastxt Macro
'

'
    ChDir "C:\Users\mcupp\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\mcupp\Desktop\Test Macros.txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not a "code for me" website - please show the code that you've used and what you have tried. I can suggest looking into `ThisWorkbook.Fullname` function to get the filepath and the name and then replacing the last three or four characters with txt in the save filepath function.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, code should be formatted a certain way. Please read the help section. I'm not sure why you rejected a friendly edit that displays the code as code. Unreadable code is less likely to be answered, and other regular users are going to edit your question in exactly the same way that I did.

Comment: The quickest way is to highlight your code and then hit `Ctrl+k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below will work with any file extension and saves the workbook as text file.

```
Sub saver()
Dim fn As String
Dim l As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
fn = wb.FullName
l = InStrRev(fn, ".")
fn = Left(fn, l)
fn = fn & "txt"

wb.SaveAs Filename:=fn, FileFormat:=xlText
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested)

```
Sub saveastxt()

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:= .Path & "\" & .Name & ".txt", _
                FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

I did not strip off the ".xlsx" from the filename, just appended the ".txt" so you might want to fix that...